# How to move the latest files alone into a folder using cmd?

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have to move my latest files alone into a folder named 'archive' using cmd .how should i do it?

for ex: i have files which are created in may,june,july,aug and sep in my_folder.

now i need to move all the files which are created in may,june,july and aug into my_archive and sep files alone have to stay in my_folder.

i used move c:\my_folder*.* c:\my_archive. but this moves all the files.  what should be the correct script for doing this?

second thing is , i am thinking of using task scheduler to run the batch file which has this move script? will this help?

Thanks,

ResKing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your date format is MM/dd/yyyy this might work:

```
@echo off

set month=%date:~0,2%
set year=%date:~-4%

mkdir temp_folder

rem move this month's files out of the way
forfiles /d +%month%/01/%year% /c "%comspec% /c move \"@path\" temp_folder"

rem move all other files to my_archive
forfiles /d -%month%/01/%year% /c "%comspec% /c move \"@path\" my_archive"

rem restore this month's files
move temp_folder\*.* .

rmdir temp_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

This batch will cycle through all old files (not from current month) and move them one by one to my_archive directory.

I'm creating a new file just in case there are no new files in this directory (I'm using a new file as a break rule for the loop). This file is deleted in the end of the batch file.

The dir parameters are to show only files and to sort them by date. you can additionally specify the timestamp you prefer:

```
/T:C - Creation
/T:A - Last Access
/T:W - Last Written
```

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET SRC_PATH=c:\my_folder
SET DST_PATH=c:\my_archive
SET MONTH=%date:~4,2%
SET YEAR=%date:~-4%
echo blah > !SRC_PATH!\to_delete.txt

for /f "skip=4 tokens=1,5 delims= " %%g in ('dir /A:-D /O:D !SRC_PATH!') do (
set date=%%g
set m=!date:~0,2!
set y=!date:~-4!
if !YEAR! gtr !y! (move !SRC_PATH!\%%h !DST_PATH!\%%h) else (
if !MONTH! gtr !m! (move !SRC_PATH!\%%h !DST_PATH!\%%h) else goto :end
) )

:end
del !SRC_PATH!\to_delete.txt
```